# Resubmit all nodes

Tags: 8, nodes

I would like to save all nodes, because I created a validation function picking data from Google Analytics.

This doesn't work:

```
$node = Node::load(nid);
$node->save();
```

Comment: That should work. What makes you think it's not?

Comment: use Drupal\node\Entity\Node; did you include this class ??

Comment: Yes, i dont have error by php, but the nodes are not updated. I make a a tini in validation field

Comment: From my exp with D7, load seems like it doesn't save when there is nothing being set, so try setting a value, `$node->title->value = $node->title->value;`

Comment: _This don't work_ It wouldn't, `Node::save()` is for a single node, not all nodes

Comment: 'save all nodes' really isn't performant either, the more nodes you have, the less likely the op will be to complete. You should implement a batch updater or something along those lines.

Comment: "I make a a tini in validation field" - validation is part of a form process, not the node saving process. So re-saving the node will not pass through any validation, which is why you are not seeing your changes. The code you have shown is working, but whatever it is you are trying to do, needs to be done a different way.

Answer (score 0):

A naive solution to your problem is to load all the nodes and save them one by one.

```
foreach (\Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple() as $node) {
  $node->save();
}
```

The above code will resave all the nodes but is not efficient and can result in a 50x error due to not enough available memory.

To do this in a more efficient way, you should only load batches of nodes.

And if you have a limit on your run time then you should use the drupal batch-api.